# ParseFile if empty from server using Android

Tags: android, file, file-upload, parse-platform

I am working on an Android application for parse.com in which I am taking image file from parse.com. I want to make a condition in which if image file is not available on server then it will not crash the application it should give a toast message "Image File Not Available" or it will show default image file.

My code is given below:

```
public static ParseUser user = getCurrentUser();

progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserInfoActivity.this, "","Downloading Image...", true);

ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) user.get("profileImage");
fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
            // Decode the Byte[] into Bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
            Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bmp, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(shader);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
            c.drawCircle(bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2,
            bmp.getWidth() / 2, paint);             

            // Get the ImageView from main.xml
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            // Set the Bitmap into the ImageView
            image.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);

            // Close progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "asfdsasa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("test","There was a problem downloading the data.");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Android API for ParseObject https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html

> has(String key) 
>             Whether this object has a particular key.

So, you should simply be able to:

```
if (getCurrentUser().has("profileImage")) {
    // fetch and show
} else {
    // use default image
}
```

You might have to fetch the data for the user before the check using `user.fetchIfNeededInBackground()`

After that you can get the data by calling `getCurrentUser().get("profileImage")`. No need to do any additional calls, as the user object has already been populated with the data from the profile image.

**Bonus:**

Looks as if you want to draw the image on a circular canvas.

The Android Bootstrap library has methods to do just that, which might be useful: https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Comment: Did you try this out? Note in your case `fileObject.getDataInBackground` should then be replaced by `getCurrentUser().fetchIfNeededInBackground()` followed by `byte[] data = getCurrentUser().get("profileImage")` if `getCurrentUser().has("profileImage")`